# NIntegrate over the surface of a 3D mesh

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I have been trying to integrate over a surface of a 3D Mesh. The sample code looks like this

```
l0 = 0.1;
COD = 0.2;
X1 = 0.0;
Y1 = 0.0;
Z1 = 0.0;
X2 = 1.0;
Y2 = 8.0;
Z2 = 1.0;
Ymid = 0.5 (Y2 + Y1);
aDim = 0.5;
reg1=Rectangle[{X1,Y1},{X2,Y2}];
reg2=Triangle[{{X1,Ymid+COD},{X1,Ymid-COD},{aDim,Ymid}}];
reg3=RegionDifference[reg1,reg2];
reg4=RegionProduct[reg3,Line[{{Z1},{Z2}}]];
elVol =5(l0/2)^3/(6\[Sqrt]2);
MeshIn = ToElementMesh[reg4, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> 0.0125}, 
"MeshOrder" -> 1, 
MeshRefinementFunction -> 
Function[{vertices, Vol}, 
Block[{x, y, z, tol}, {x, y, z} = Mean[vertices]; tol = 0.05; 
If[y < Ymid + tol && y > Ymid - tol && x > aDim - tol , 
 Vol > elVol, Vol > 5]]]]
```

I want to integrate a function

```
f[x_,y_,z_] = x y^2 + z^2;
```

over the surface `x = 1`. I can directly integrate using the command

```
NIntegrate[f[x,y,z],{y,0,8},{z,0,1}];
```

Is it possible to integrate over the finite element mesh using something like this

```
NIntegrate[f[x,y,z], {x, y, z} \[Element] MeshIn]
```

and I also want to choose `x = 1`. I need this because i want to integrate the finite element solution which is a global interpolation function over the surface of the mesh. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: what is the value for COD?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas my apologies i missed it. I have edited my question now.

Comment: I get compile messages. I'd fix those since I assume the resulting mesh is not what you want otherwise.

Comment: @user21 I am sorry for the sloppy posting. The mesh generation works now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
NIntegrate[f[1, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] MeshIn]
172.063
```

Comment: Thank you, this works correctly.